# Getting video snapshot for thumbnail

Tags: ios, xcode, video, avfoundation

I am recording a video from the iPhone camera by using the AVCam code provided from apple.

After the video is recorded it is saved to the photos library.

A new view is then loaded, here I need to have an image thumbnail of the video.

I have a path to the video:

```
file://localhost/private/var/mobile/Applications/ED45DEFC-ABF9-4A5E-9102-21680CC1448E/tmp/output.mov
```

I can't seem to figure how to get the first frame of the video to use as a thumbnail.

Any help would be very appreciated and thank you for your time.

---

**EDIT**

I ended up using this, I'm not sure why it returns the image sideways?

```
- (UIImage*)loadImage {

    AVURLAsset *asset = [[AVURLAsset alloc] initWithURL:vidURL options:nil];
    AVAssetImageGenerator *generate = [[AVAssetImageGenerator alloc] initWithAsset:asset];
    NSError *err = NULL;
    CMTime time = CMTimeMake(1, 60);
    CGImageRef imgRef = [generate copyCGImageAtTime:time actualTime:NULL error:&err];
    NSLog(@"err==%@, imageRef==%@", err, imgRef);

    return [[UIImage alloc] initWithCGImage:imgRef];

}
```

Answer (score 45, accepted):

To *fix* the thumbnail orientation set `appliesPreferredTrackTransform` to `YES` in the `AVAssetImageGenerator` instance. If you add your own video composition, you'll need to include the right transform to rotate the video as wanted.

```
generate.appliesPreferredTrackTransform = YES;
```

Remember to release the obtained image reference with `CGImageRelease`.

To request multiple thumbnails it's better to do asynchronously with `generateCGImagesAsynchronouslyForTimes:completionHandler:`.

Comment: Gives me an error AVErrorOperationNotSupportedForAsset . plz help

Comment: I can't help you without information, ask a new question with your specific problem. And read the documentation perhaps.

Comment: nice one liner solution :)