# iOS how to insert an inline photo or video thumbnail in a UITextView?

Tags: ios, iphone, audio, uitextview, email-attachments

I'm looking at two apps: native iOS Mail and Evernote and see that both of them allow embedding of little thumbnails representing audio files inline with text. Is this a native feature of a UITextView?

**How can I add an inline photo or video thumbnail into a UITextView, like the Evernote app?**

Comment: did you complete it? if yes, share sample code.

Comment: Im also interested on this!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On iOS 7 or later, you can use NSTextAttachment to insert an inline image to UITextView. See this for an example: https://stackoverflow.com/a/20930656/1262685

For the video thumbnail, you'll need to create the thumbnail yourself. Here's one way to do it: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19530997/1262685

Comment: Can I make the video play inside the textView? Also, it is possible to click the attachment and see if it is a video or an image?