# react native - get MOV thumbnail

Tags: android, ios, react-native, thumbnails, video-thumbnails

I am researching about implementing a custom Gallery in Android and iOS using React native. The interesting thing is that with tag `Image`, I can show the thumbnail of `mp4` video.

However, I receive the error: `Error decoding image data <NSData 0x7fc2cb34dec0; 2516731 bytes>` when coming to MOV video files.

Do you know anyway to solve the issue? Or is there any better ways to show thumbnail instead of using tag `Image`.

Comment: You may have to write your own native module to do this. These links could help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19530800/getting-a-thumbnail-of-a-mov-video-ios and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15735716/how-can-i-get-a-frame-sample-jpeg-from-a-video-mov

Comment: @Andrew: Thank you, after a few hours researching, I got the same idea as you do. Do you know any link related to Swift?