# How to displaying thumbnail images of .mov for UITableView cells in IOS

Tags: ios, iphone

hi im very new to ios i have read books beginner books and intermediate books, i understand ios put there are certain things i cant get done. im trying to put a thumbnail image of a .mov video into a cell like the youtube app i figured out how to do the thumbnail into `UIImageView`

```
NSString *videoPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"e.mov" ofType:nil];
NSURL *videoURl = [[NSURL alloc ] initFileURLWithPath:videoPath];
AVURLAsset *asset = [[AVURLAsset alloc] initWithURL:videoURl options:nil];
AVAssetImageGenerator *generate = [[AVAssetImageGenerator alloc] initWithAsset:asset];
generate.appliesPreferredTrackTransform = YES;
NSError *err = NULL;
CMTime time = CMTimeMake(0.0, 600);
CMTime actualTime;

CGImageRef imgRef = [generate copyCGImageAtTime:time actualTime:&actualTime error:&err];

UIImage *img = [[UIImage alloc] initWithCGImage:imgRef];
[self.myImageView setImage:img];
```

thats what i have done to get the thumbnail image to the UIImageView on a standard UIViewController, i just cant figure out how to do it in a `UITableViewCell` *cell;

I have 18 videos i want to display in the cells as thumbnails and once the cell is touched prepareForSegue: method is activated then it goes to the detailViewCOntroller

```
NSString *videoPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"e.mov" ofType:nil];
```

How do i make this a `NSMutableArray` and put it in

```
NSURL *videoURl = [[NSURL alloc ] initFileURLWithPath:videoPath];
```

and make it work in cells

basically i cant figure out how to display an array of videos as thumbnails in cells 
please help

Comment: what is that you want, you are saying that you cannot set the image in a cell. create a UIImageView and set it as subview of the cell.

Comment: try if this works for you. http://stackoverflow.com/a/19530997/3251886

Comment: i dont now how to put a thumbnail image of the video into an array so i can display them into the cell

Comment: my code works that i put here im able to display a single video as a thumbnail in an UIImageView now im trying to figure out how to display it in cells so i can display all 18 of my videos as an array to the cell

Comment: i want to display my videos like the youtube app does

Comment: in the 'cellForRowAtIndexPath' create a UIImageView object. Set the thumbnail image to the UIImageView and set this imageview obj as subclass to cell - [cell.contentView addSubView:imageViewobj];

Comment: whats the contentView in reference to

Comment: the destination of the current view that the cells are in

Comment: UIImageView *img1 = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:img];
    
    cell.thumbnailImageView.image = img1;

Comment: this is what i have in the cellForRowAtIndexPath method

Comment: cell.thumbnailImageView.image = [cell.contentView addSubview:image];

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
   static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
   UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier   forIndexPath:indexPath] ;

   AVURLAsset *asset = [[AVURLAsset alloc] initWithURL:videoPath options:nil];
   AVAssetImageGenerator *generate = [[AVAssetImageGenerator alloc] initWithAsset:asset];
   CMTime time = CMTimeMake(1, 30);
   CGImageRef thumbImg = [generate copyCGImageAtTime:time actualTime:NULL error:&err];


   if (cell == nil)
   {
     cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
   }
   cell.imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
   cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:thumbImg];
   return cell;
}
```

Comment: where do i put this in cellForRowAtIndexPath

Comment: @user2257386 : Where you need to display image. if need to display in each cell means see cellForRowAtIndexPath in your table view code..

Comment: i put it in but nothing comes up in the cell just plain

Comment: do i use NSURL to get path cause i did and nothing happens

Comment: NSString *vidPath; to NSURL *vidURL;

Comment: thanks so much it worked after i set the delegates and datasource

Comment: if your problem solved means you can upvote and accept solution. it will helps others to identify solution for these kind of issue in future.

Answer (score 0):

Here it is... [get screenshot first frame of the video](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9145968/getting-video-snapshot-for-thumbnail)

```
- (UIImage*)loadImage {

    AVURLAsset *asset = [[AVURLAsset alloc] initWithURL:vidURL options:nil];
    AVAssetImageGenerator *generate = [[AVAssetImageGenerator alloc] initWithAsset:asset];
    NSError *err = NULL;
    CMTime time = CMTimeMake(1, 60);
    CGImageRef imgRef = [generate copyCGImageAtTime:time actualTime:NULL error:&err];
    NSLog(@"err==%@, imageRef==%@", err, imgRef);

    return [[UIImage alloc] initWithCGImage:imgRef];

}
```

Comment: yeah now how do i put all the video thumbnails into an array to display in the cells