# thumbnail of a video on clicking video file in iOS simulator

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, video

I have a video in gallery. on clicking it  tries to open,but instead of that i want to show a thumbnail of video in uiimageview.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Getting thumbnail from a video url or data in IPhone SDK](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1347562/getting-thumbnail-from-a-video-url-or-data-in-iphone-sdk)

Comment: Go through this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9145968/getting-video-snapshot-for-thumbnail

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
AVURLAsset *asset;
if ([url isFileURL]) {
   asset = [[AVURLAsset alloc] initWithURL:url options:nil];
}
AVAssetImageGenerator *gen = [[AVAssetImageGenerator alloc] initWithAsset:asset];
gen.appliesPreferredTrackTransform = YES;
CMTime time = CMTimeMakeWithSeconds(0.0, 600);
NSError *error = nil;
CMTime actualTime;

CGImageRef image = [gen copyCGImageAtTime:time actualTime:&actualTime error:&error];
UIImage *thumb = [[UIImage alloc] initWithCGImage:image];
UIImage *finalThumpnailImage = [HPLUtility createThumpnailImageFromTheImage:thumb]; //Resized image.
CGImageRelease(image);
return finalThumpnailImage;
```