# get thumbnail image for video file which is in NSDATA ios

Tags: ios, video, nsdata

I have a NSDATA for a video file. How do I extract the thumbnail Image out of it. Also I am not allowed to write the NSDATA for the video file on to the local documents directory. I have looked into it but not able to find the solution. Could someone let me know how to achieve it?

Comment: do you have video in your project locally or you are downloading from server?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9145968/getting-video-snapshot-for-thumbnail this might help you

Comment: I have download it from the server and its in NSDATA format. Also I cannot save the video in the local as the app is not allowed to save any audio or video in local. How do I do that?

Comment: yes you can save audio or video.